# How to use my PC Chrome as a mobile chrome permanently?

Tags: google-chrome

I use the Chrome in my laptop with Windows 7 OS, and the Chrome on Windows provides a `Device Mode`(shortcut is `F12`) so that it can simulate a specific mobile device to get and display a Web page in a Chrome tab as follow.

[image]

However, such `Device Mode` is only limited on a single Chrome tab, so when you close the tab and open a new one, the new tab get and show the web page as normal, not as in the `Device Mode`.

So my question is **How to set the `Device Mode` permanently, and when I open a new tab in the Chrome, it runs on `Device Mode` by default**. Is there any method or plug-in can help me to achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this is not applicable as Google created that mode for inspection purposes only not for navigating or viewing.

So you will need a smartphone simulator like the one which is provided by Android SDK or the IOS simulator which comes with XCODE on mac, or you can use a real smartphone of course, and you can inspect on it via your PC using ADOBE Edge Inspect extension on chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome inspector mode is designed with testing in mind, and isn't intended for regular browser use. You might try a device simulator tool, like what's included in Xcode or Eclipse IDE.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is something what you are looking for

[Google chrome plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mobile-browser-emulator/lbofcampnkjmiomohpbaihdcbjhbfepf?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

You can open devtool automatically with chrome switches, so i suppose that you can reach your goal with the correct one... our only problem is that chrome's switches are thousands... [that's the documentation, good reading](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/run-chromium-with-flags) :D ([unofficial documentation here](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/))